# Is there an equivalent class to HtmlTextWriter in dotnet core/corefx?

Tags: c#, html, .net, .net-core

Many libraries that create html rely on HtmlTextWriter. Is there an equivalent to this class in the new corefx?

Here are a few projects that rely on HtmlTextWriter:
https://github.com/darthfubumvc/htmltags
https://fluenttags.codeplex.com/

An alternative question might be: "What is the best way to generate html using dotnet core / corefx?"

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24169

Answer (score 8):

There's a super easy fix that I've tested working on .NET core 3.1 and .NET 5. Just install NuGet package HtmlTextWriter in your .NET core project and that's it.

Comment: According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.0 no .NET CORE Framekwork supports HtmlTextWriter

Comment: The NuGet package is for .NET standard but it works in .NET core too. I have tested this. Anyone who is looking to migrate can easily test this before spending more effort.

Answer (score 3):

`.NET Core 2.0` [does not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter?view=netcore-2.0) `HtmlTextWriter` class.

You could work around this by moving your logic, which uses `HtmlTextWriter`, to the class library `.NET Standard 2.0`. Then you will be able to reference this class library from both - `.NET Core` and `.NET Framework` projects.

Comment: You you took the class library approach, my understanding is that although .NET Core would compile, you would not be able to run the application on Linux where the .NET Framework is not installed.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.0 HtmlTextWriter is not supported by any .NET CORE Framework

Answer (score 3):

You can use a normal `TextWriter` with extension-methods if you don't care about formatting and indentation or tabs.

Using extension-methods to add-back `WriteBeginTag` and others will give you source-level compatibility, but because you're still using `TextWriter` without additional state you won't be able to correctly implement indentation unless you store your indentation state in a separate object and carry it around with the `TextWriter` (I did think about using thread-local-storage to make it implicit, but as ASP.NET Core uses `async` a lot I don't think it's wise to use thread-local-storage for this purpose).