# What replace the System.Web.UI Namespace in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I need to use an HtmlTextWriter for writing an HTML file with HtmlContentBuilder in .NET 6

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui?view=netframework-4.8 this namespace doesn't exist anymore.

What replaces the System.Web.UI Namespace or my HtmlTextWriter in .NET 6 ?

Comment: See if below thread helps you.. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185667/is-there-an-equivalent-class-to-htmltextwriter-in-dotnet-core-corefx>

Comment: [According to the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.xhtmltextwriter?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to), we can see that it is not compatible with the .net core platform.